# Python aiomysql puts a set of quote around my query argument

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using python's aiomysql execute function to execute sql queries.

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def select(sql,args=None,size=None):
    log(sql,args)
    global __pool
    with (yield from __pool) as conn:
        cur = yield from conn.cursor()
        yield from cur.execute(sql.replace('?','%s'),args or ())
        if size:
            rs = yield from cur.fetchmany(size)
        else:
            rs = yield from cur.fetchall()
    __pool.close()
    yield from __pool.wait_closed()

    return rs
```

In the test function I did

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def test():
    yield from create_pool(loop=loop,user='app',passwd='app')
    sql = 'select ? from ?'
    arg = ['id','users']
    rs = yield from select(sql,arg)
    print(rs)

    global __pool
    __pool.close()
    yield from __pool.wait_closed()
```

In the terminal I got an error

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users'' at line 1")
```

There appears to be a set of quote around users. I tried changing the last ? to %s and that somehow worked, apparently the ? worked for id but not for users. Why is there a set of quote around users and how can I fix it?

Thank your for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL parameters *cannot* be used for metadata with MySQL. You will need to sanitize the value and substitute it normally.

Comment: would you mind elaborating a bit and maybe give an example. I'm a bit confused to what you mean

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that might have the same problem, it seems like it's impossible to use arg to refer to the tables, the table must be specified before passing into execute